# How to avoid binding of some fields?

Tags: validation, binding, playframework

Using the validation from PlayFramework and the data binding, is it possible, via (maybe) a decorator, to avoid binding some fields?

For example, I have this model :

```
class User extends Model {
    @Required
    @Email
    public String email;

    // I'd like to avoid setting this
    public String password;
}
```

and in my model :

```
Store store = new Store();
Binder.bindBean(params.getRootParamNode(), store, null);        
validation.valid(store);
```

If the user POST email AND password, password will be also set, but I don't want to.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to persist the data, but you want it to be bound as part of the automatic binding, then you can use the @Transient annotation...

Example

```
class User extends Model {
    @Required
    @Email
    public String email;

    // I'd like to avoid setting this
    @Transient
    public String password;
}
```

If you don't want it to be bound at all, then use the [NoBinding annotation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers#nobinding)

```
@play.data.binding.NoBinding
```

Example

```
public class User extends Model {
    @NoBinding("profile") public boolean isAdmin;
    @As("dd, MM yyyy") Date birthDate;
    public String name;
}
```